# Updating Visual Studio for Mac to test beta iOS 13 Versions

Tags: macos, xamarin

I can't update to the beta versions of VS for mac. I'm on a Macbook Pro 2019, MacOS 10.14.6, which I updated to because I had the problem on the previous version as well.

I've followed the instructions at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/updater-troubleshooting?view=vsmac-2019

but that didn't help. Is there something else I can do/check?

My VS for Mac is:

=== Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 for Mac ===

Version 8.2 (build 1124)
Installation UUID: efce2198-73f8-4d8f-b0ab-99c04aa9500a
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 5.14.0.85 (d16-2-fix-mac-updates / 86973979)

```
Package version: 600000311
```

=== Mono Framework MDK ===

Runtime:
    Mono 6.0.0.311 (2019-02/494641b300c) (64-bit)
    Package version: 600000311

=== NuGet ===

Version: 5.1.0.6013

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.0.0-preview6-27804-01
    2.1.12
    2.1.11
    2.1.9
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview6-012264/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.0.100-preview6-012264
    2.1.701
    2.1.700
    2.1.505
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.0.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.6.11
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Updater ===

Version: 11

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 10.3 (14492.2)
Build 10G8

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Not Installed

=== Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===

Java SDK: Not Found

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Android Device Manager ===

Version: 1.2.0.58
Hash: d03e3ea
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-2~1
Build date: 2019-08-06 08:24:06 UTC

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 12.14.0.114 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Hash: c6691164
Branch: d16-2
Build date: 2019-07-29 15:54:05-0400

=== Xamarin Designer ===

Version: 16.2.0.391
Hash: 216490cf5
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-2-xcode11
Build date: 2019-08-06 08:21:56 UTC

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 802001124
Git revision: 0797bb4dfcd2cbad030d7fce609e247e23f855ca
Build date: 2019-07-26 12:13:29+00
Build branch: release-8.2-xcode11
Xamarin extensions: d663a25405cd5e7d0b0deefd2a26d548680f16f5

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.14.6
Darwin 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0
    Thu Jun 20 18:42:21 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-4903.270.47~4/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Comment: do you get an error? can you post some screenshots?

Comment: unfortunately the only error I get is a message box to inform me that the installtion failed. Typical Xamarin fare, really.

Comment: I dont have mac in front of me now but there is under help menu somewhere "logs", you may find something there

Comment: There's an update.log, but it now lists the successful update and nothing else. I'll have a poke around in the directory. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately/unfortunately, the problem seems to have resolved itself. It seems the installer got over itself and managed to do its job. Not very satisfying, I know.

I'll leave the question up, in the hope that someone can point me to an error log/explanation.